# A Jpa query annotation to return results as key value pairs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a users table and I am trying to use annotated Queries in spring boot to get a result set. I am able to get result set as a list, but that does not have field names. How do I get the result set with field name as key and value pairs?
Current response [[1,"Jay"]] , what I want to do is {"id":1,"Name":"Jay"}

-----Here is my repository class-----

```
 @Repository
 public interface UsersauthRepository2 extends JpaRepository<Users2,Long> {
 @Query("select id,name,email from Users u where LOWER(email) = LOWER(:email) and LOWER(u.password) = LOWER(:password)")
 List<Users2> querybyemail(@Param("email") String email,@Param("password") String password);
  }
```

Comment: There is no "NamedQuery" there. That is JPQL, and is Spring Data JPA API, not JPA API

Comment: Edited ,Thank you @NeilStockton

Comment: I converted the result set into String array,which was easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request doesn't return fields names.
If you need to get them :

1. You have them already as method argument
2. You need to use reflection.

Good luck

Comment: Will try these,Thank you.